# Print DH params in DER format in OpenSSL in C

Tags: c, openssl

Is there a way to print out the DH parameters from `DH` struct in OpenSSL?

Comment: Given your question "Print DH params in DER format", what is the relevance of DER here? Are you looking for [DHparams_print()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/DHparams_print.html)?

Comment: It is important. The function you suggest unfortunately prints it out in PEM format.

Comment: Since DER is a binary format, how do you want to print to DER?

Comment: The program would print it out into a file.

Comment: No, `DHparams_print[_fp]` prints labelled textual values, which is not PEM. `PEM_write[_bio]_DHparams` prints/writes PEM. 'print' normally means human-readable and DER is not human-readable, so we say 'writes'. `i2d_DHparams{,_fp,_bio}` writes DER to a memory buffer, stdio `FILE*` or OpenSSL `BIO*` (which can in turn be a file, socket, memory buffer, or something else) in the same way as the `i2d` routines for all other OpenSSL types. In 1.0.2 up the PEM and i2d routines have `DHxparams` versions which use X9.42 format instead of PKCS3 format. To be clear, these are params and not keys.

Comment: Thank you. Would you please give an example of calling `i2d_DHparams_fp`? I have no idea what arguments it takes and I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: What version of openssl are you using?

Comment: `SSLeay_version(SSLEAY_VERSION)` says that "OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User [dave_thompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085) basically gave you the answer in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53561551/print-dh-params-in-der-format-in-openssl-in-c?noredirect=1#comment93991132_53561551). For the version that you are using, the function `i2d_DHparams_fp()` is not available, you will have to use [`i2d_DHparams()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/dh.html) to get a buffer of unsigned chars and then write that to a file. Something like this.

```
/* Just an example */
DH *dh = DH_get_2048_256();
unsigned char *der = NULL;

/* On success, len contains the length of the buffer */
int len = i2d_DHparams(dh, &der);

/* Open file, write bytes to it, close file */
FILE *fder = fopen("dhparams.der", "wb");
fwrite(der, len, 1, fder);
fclose(fder);

/* Done with the buffer */
OPENSSL_free(der);
```

Error checking has to be added.

You can check that it worked by using the `asn1parse` tool, like this:

```
$ openssl asn1parse -inform der -in dhparams.der
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 521 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim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
  265:d=1  hl=4 l= 256 prim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
```